# SubViews MainView in a Xib are not displayed in iOS why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

The problem is View is loaded but the inner elements are not loaded or did not appear why?

**the xib image is:**[image]

and the corresponding `.h` is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface DownloadView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *downloadFilename;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *downloadpercentage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *downloadprogressBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *downloadCancel;

@end
```

`.m` file is:

```
#import "DownloadView.h"

@implementation DownloadView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DownloadView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DownloadView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The calling file is:

```
polygonView = [[DownloadView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, height-170, width, 100)];


        polygonView.downloadFilename.text = @"Initiating Download...";
        [polygonView.downloadprogressBar setProgress:0];
        polygonView.downloadpercentage.text = @"0%";

        [window addSubview:polygonView];
```

What is the Problem ?

Debugger update:[image]

The output is:[image]

Comment: what happened after you add the subview to window ?What you are doing is correct. There is nothing wrong. Maybe there should be an issue with the window property!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Its showing the sub view but not showing the elements inside that subView.

Comment: may be the frame is wrong, try to add this line after you load the xib. self.view.frame=self.bounds i.e right after the loadNibNamed line.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Nope I tried both options its not showing up the inner views

Comment: could you post a screenshot ? Also put a breakpoint right after [self addSubview:self.view]; and try to print out the description of self.view and self. See if anyting is nil or not.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Its not showing any element in the self.view when I debug as you said... Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110913/discussion-between-group-and-teja-nandamuri).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't create custom UIView like this, it will not work. I use different way for reusable custom components which is:

1. Create new view controller in the storyboard, change its frame, and customize it.
2. Give it an identifier
3. In all places you want to use in storyboard, just create Container view and embed your custom view controller.
4. If you want to use it programmatically. Just instantiate it from storyboard with the identifier. Resize its view frame and add it as a subview.

Comment: Sorry Hossam I think you don't know about custom xibs

Comment: I know and I hate them actually, too many issues happen while using them, then I decided to use the method I told you about. If its not clear, let me know to give you a simple example.

Comment: Thank you Hossam, I'm not interested in that stuff;